# It wont draw my rectangle (pygame on prdroid)

Tags: python, pygame, pydroid

The screen wont fill and it says there is no fill cmd for screen, what did I do wrong?

```py
import pygame
    
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display
set_mode((0, 0))

white = (255, 255, 255)
Square =(0, 0, 0)

loop = True
while loop:
    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Square, pygame)Rect(100, 100, 200, 200)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: hey, I'm new to python and basically just started learning, I don't know what that is

Comment: This should be on a single line `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))`

Comment: @ChainzGames you have a lot of errors `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))`, this is how you fix the error message and there are indentation errors there too i think

Comment: @IainShelvington i edited it, for a new bug iv found trying to add a rectangle to the screen

Comment: @ChainzGames your syntax is all messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in your code:

<s>`screen = pygame.display`</s>
<s>`set_mode((0, 0))`</s>

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
```

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(screen, Square, pygame)Rect(100, 100, 200, 200)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, Square, pygame.Rect(100, 100, 200, 200))
```

More than that, the event loop is missing. This can cause your application to freeze. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

Correct program:

```py
import pygame
    
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

white = (255, 255, 255)
Square = (0, 0, 0)

loop = True
while loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False

    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Square, pygame.Rect(100, 100, 200, 200))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @ChainzGames Please follow the link: https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/It-wont-draw-my-rectangle#main.py This is the working example. Same code as in the answer. No error.

Comment: never mind it works now, thank you for the help (mainly with the indentions :) )